# Swedish characters in google geocode request

Tags: google-maps, utf-8, google-geocoding-api

I´m trying to use google geocoding api but I can´t get it work with the Swedish letters 'å ä ö'. I send the question as this 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=götagatan 24 &components=country:SE&sensor=false
Don´t work. If I use a address without the Swedish charachter it works fine. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=nygatan 22 &components=country:SE&sensor=false

How can I in the request Point out that it´s a Swedish charachter?

Comment: Add `&language=se` and you will get `<formatted_address>Götagatan 24, 432 42 Varberg, Sweden</formatted_address>`

Comment: thought my country:se was the same, Thanks!