# how do I tell Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to use Finnish (or Swedish) characters?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, encoding

I try to query LatLong-coordinates from a Finnish address with Google Maps geocoder. The aim is to draw a marker on a map where the address is pointing. It works with English characters so far but Finnish (and Swedish) characters 'ä, ö, å' causes trouble. I found this: [Swedish characters in google geocode request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132237/swedish-characters-in-google-geocode-request)

, but it didn't help.

For example this address doesn't have any problems:

```
"Mannerheimintie 10, Helsinki, Finland"
```

But this one has:

```
"Läntinen polku 10, Espoo, Finland"
```

Here's my code:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
  'address': address
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
...
... // do something
...
```

I tried with these parameters also but didn't work:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
  'address': address,
  'region': 'FI' // I tried also with 'language':'fi'
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
...
... // do something
...
```

The API in use is Google Maps JavaScript API v3. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

So how do I tell this API to use Finnish (or Swedish) characters?

Comment: Your problematic address works on this page [from the Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).  You probably need this `<meta charset="utf-8">` and/or to control the character encoding of your page.

Answer (score 0):

When you include the google js files try adding `&language=fi` to localize.

Comment: Thanks @Paolo Casciello! But didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

See the localization section of the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization

You can add the `language` attribute to the Google JS files to use a specific language.

For Finnish, use the following `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=fi">
```

---

**EDIT**

So, it seems that adding the `language` attribute just seems to control the language used by Google when rendering the results. For example, when specifying `fi`, the map produced would have everything in Finnish.

I used the [Geocoding example provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) to create this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ciroluwi/1/edit?html,js,output

Now, admittedly my knowledge of Finnish geography is limited but it seems to me that the address: "Läntinen polku 10, Espoo, Finland", provided by the OP is being located correctly.

Comment: okay I put .../js?language=fi&region=fi. Not working. Firebug says that 7sFI is "undefined" as well as 9sfi is "undefined". Am I doing something wrong? @Sid

Comment: @hemppa I edited my answer and provided a JSBin link. See if that produces the right results for you

Comment: Problem solved. Was nothing to do with the code above. Thanks for all answers though.